# Representative Sample - Air travel passengers and gender ratio

Tags: inference, descriptive-statistics, sample, bias, representative

I have a question regarding the ways to build a representative sample for a research study focusing on air travel passengers in 3 different world regions (NA, EMEA, APAC)

I think I should use the gender ratio of leisure and business air passengers respectively for each region when disseminating the sample / analysing the data
in order to draw meaningful conclusions. Is that correct?

However, I do not have this data, and I am not sure I can find them (even though we could speculate that in business travels the proportion of men is higher).

Could the general gender ratio ~1:1 be used, or would it make the sample / analysis non-representative (especially for business air passengers)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Shouldn't the age group also be considered when building the sample? For instance, business passengers might, on average, be older than leisure passenger, and perhaps this should also be taken into account. Thanks!

Comment: I think that time is also an issue. As you noted business and leisure are two different groups that might also fly on different times. When you have data of an entire year that is not an issue, but when you have part of a year you should take note of that.